# Why does Zinc not have magnetic properties despite it being a transition element?

Tags: transition-metals, magnetism

I know Zinc has a full d-orbital which might contribute to the effect. But it is not ferromagnetic or paramagnetic like other transition element complexes. Why is that?

Comment: Well, paramagnetism and all the \*ferr\*magnetisms depend on unpaired electrons, so …

Comment: "has a d-orbital which might contribute to the effect" That's not the right conclusion.

Comment: Everything has magnetic properties. Zinc, in particular, is **dia**magnetic.

Comment: [This Minute Physics video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hFAOXdXZ5TM) has a pretty accessible explanation of magnetism in different materials